# Error: The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have this error **The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked** here while trying to show comments which i stored in firebase

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('news')
      .doc(widget.postId)
      .collection('comments')
      .orderBy("CommentTime", descending: true)
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }
    return ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) {
        final commentData =
            doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

        return Comment(
          text: (commentData("CommentText")).toString(),   // error here
          user: commentData("CommentedBy"),   // error here
          time: formatDate(commentData("CommentTime")),   // error here
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  },
)
```

and this is comment class

```
class Comment extends StatelessWidget {
  final String user;
  final String text;
  final String time;
  const Comment(
      {super.key, required this.user, required this.text, required this.time});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey[300],
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
      ),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
      child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
        // comment
        Text(text),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 5,
        ),
        // user, time
        Row(
          children: [
            Text(
              user,
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
            ),
            const Text(" . "),
            Text(
              time,
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to cast this into String but nothing has happened, i want to know what is this error and how to solve it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, which is so silly

I didn't notice the combination of square brackets/parentheses here:

```
           text: commentData("CommentText").toString(),  
                                user: commentData("CommentedBy"),  
                     time: formatDate(commentData("CommentTime")),
```

I changed it into

```
text: commentData["CommentText"],
                                user: commentData["CommentedBy"],
                                time: formatDate(commentData["CommentTime"]),
```